# jQuery Mobile Slider with step

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/udcrk1yr/1/):

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label for="slider-10">Slider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider-10" id="slider-10" min="0" max="999" step="1" value="0">
</form>

<form>
    <label for="slider-10">Slider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider-10" id="slider-10" min="0" max="99" step="1" value="0">
</form>
```

I'm having issues with the step function. For the bottom slider it steps as expected, that is to say by 1. When I change the max though in the top slider the step function starts behaving unexpectedly stepping by 10's.

Any thoughts or ideas on why this occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior just seems to be how JQuery Mobile handles the wide interval on smaller screens.  If I increase the width of the result pane in your fiddle, the 0-999 slider doesn't do the irregular step anymore.  The same behavior is shown when reducing the pane to very small sizes (for me the 0-99 slider started stepping by 3 after the pane got small enough).

I'd like to point out, though, that while the slider appears to be stepping by 10 by dragging the control, the step you've defined in your HTML is still enforced.  If you use the arrow keys on your keyboard or the arrow controls next to the slider, the slider steps by the correct amount.  If the defined step were really broken here then even those input methods would be stepping by 10 as well.